# SQLite & SQL

Tags: sqlite, c, sql

Есть ли функция, которая принимает имя столбца? Или как в запрос передать определенное имя столбца в качестве переменной?

Вот есть такой код:

```
char const *sql1 = "select SUM(@x) from t5;";

rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql1, callback3, NULL, &errmsg);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    // если ошибка при выполнении запроса
    printf("%sn", errmsg);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    exit(1);
}
```

Куда результат поступает, если я все правильно написала? Что нужно написать в callback3, чтобы получить нужную мне сумму?

Comment: какой запрос? что нужно сделать?

Comment: нужно посчитать сумму каждого столбца. но поскольку столбцов может быть миллион, то не логично писать миллион запросов с разными именами столбцов.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получение данных о таблице, отсюда можно выдрать имена всех столбцов, а на их основании уже выполнять запросы.

```
pragma table_info(table_name);
```

В вашем запросе результат поступает в функцию callback1