# Как сделать проверку на существование столбца в SQLite3 в PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, sqlite3

Всем привет.

Внутри цикла мне нужно сделать проверку есть ли такой-то столбец в таблице БД SQLite3 и если нет, то добавить такой столбец и записать в него полученные данные, если же столбец есть, то просто обновить в нём данные.

```
foreach($metrica as $key => $value){
   // Проверка есть ли столбец с именем $value[0]
   if (!true){ // если ложь, то
      // Добавим новый столбец так:
      // 'ALTER TABLE metrica ADD COLUMN `'.$value[0].'`'
      // Добавим в новый столбец данные...
      // 'INSERT...'
   } else {
      // 'UPDATE...'
   }

}
```

Не могу найти как сделать саму проверку на существование столбца в SQLite3, чтобы можно было запихнуть в условие if(), чтобы возвращало true/false.

В самой документации [sqlite.org](http://sqlite.org/lang.html) искал, но то ли не нашёл, то ли не увидел .. да и много где ещё искал, но ответа не нашёл ... может кто здесь подсказать?

(Заранее названия столбцов не знаю и их может быть весьма много, поэтому только в цикле...)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [SQLite & SQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/116780/sqlite-sql)

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info

Answer (score 1):

Как указанно в комментариях для решения данной задачи можно использовать:
`pragma table_info(table_name);` т.е. получить список всех столбцов и уже в зависимости от этого строить запрос, т.е. Создавать столбцы - если их нет и заполнять данными, или если они есть - заполнять их данными, т.е.:

```
foreach($metrics as $key => $value){
  // Получаем данные о всех столбцах таблицы metrica
  $arr_cl = $connection->execute(
    'pragma table_info(metrica)'
  )->fetchAll('assoc');

  $found = false;

  // Смотрим есть ли вообще у нас в таблице metrica такой столбец (string)$value[0]
  foreach($arr_cl as $int => $val){
    if (in_array((string)$value[0], $val)) {
        $found = true; // Cтолбец найден
        break; // Остановим выполнение цикла
    }
  }

  // Проверяем был ли найден столбец, и если нет, то добавим такой столбец в БД
  if (!$found){
    $connection->execute(
        'ALTER TABLE metrica ADD COLUMN `'.(string)$value[0].'` INTEGER'
    );
  }

  // Вставим данные в таблицу (string)$value[0]
  $rrr = $connection->execute(
    'INSERT INTO metrica (`date`, "'.(string)$value[0].'") VALUES ("'.$ga_date.'", '.(int)$value[1].')'
  );
}
```